# Help understanding difference between current and voltage transformers

Tags: voltage, transformer, current-transformer

I did see a previous question on this but I’m still a bit lost.

Here is my simple summary: A CT and VT are the exact same thing. However in the case of a CT you design your number of turns to target an output current and you don’t care what the voltage is. In a VT you design your number of turns to target an output voltage and you don’t care what the current is. In both cases there is still an input voltage/current and an output voltage/current. It’s just that you are only paying attention to one or the other in each case.

Is that accurate?

Comment: In a CT, you still care what the voltage is in order to not saturate your core. Search for _burden resistor_.

Comment: In a way, yes. VT is designed to reflect the input/primary voltage, while CT is designed to reflect the input/primary current.

Comment: Exactly the same is a stretch.  And variance of the secondary voltage of a VT allows measurement of primary voltage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, keeping in mind that current transformers and voltage transformers are separate animals from power transformers.  They are used to measure a current or voltage while providing isolation.

Current transformers are often toroids or other closed cores through which the current-carrying conductor passes as shown in the Littelfuse version below.  The devices have many turns on the secondary and affect the conductor only slightly, and provide a current proportional to the conductor current.  Of course, you could wrap turns from the conductor around the toroid, increasing your signal at a cost of increasing the series inductance.  But they are generally used in measuring very high currents, so the signal strength is not a problem.  They can be much larger and have integral insulation stacks for high voltage power lines.  The goal is to measure current accurately without adding load.

[image]

Voltage transformers are used to provide accurate real-time measurements very high (KV) voltages.  They can be capacitive or inductive, and are used for providing a ratiometric representation of a high voltage line.  Capacitive voltage transformers can be used in applications where high frequencies are present, as in comms over power.  Once again, the plan is to not provide much of a load; at 100's of KV, even milliamperes can be real power.  Some inductive voltage transformers are shown below from arteche.com:

[image]

Most of us don't cross paths with either of these, but stick with power or switching transformers.  They work on the same principle, but power transformers have efficiency-related losses and other issues (resistive losses, eddy current losses, less than 100% mutual inductance) which means that their voltage and current do not *exactly* act in a ratiometric manner.  These transformers are specifically designed NOT to provide power and to reduce these errors, so the outputs are a faithful representation of their inputs.

Comment: thanks how do they differ from power transformers? Aren’t they all still transformer?

Comment: They work on the same principle, but power transformers have efficiency-related losses and other issues (resistive losses, eddy current losses, less than 100% mutual inductance) which means that their voltage and current do not exactly act in a ratiometric manner.  These transformers are specifically designed NOT to provide power and to reduce these errors, so the outputs are a faithful representation of their inputs.

Answer (score 4):

Any transformer is fundamentally one thing; an impedance converter. If you have an ideal 10:1 step-down transformer with a 1 Ω load on the secondary then, the impedance looking into the primary is 100 Ω. It's the turns-ratio squared that converts the impedance.

So, if the turns ratio is 1:10 (step-up), the 1 Ω load on the secondary looks like 0.01 Ω on the primary. Clearly, one of the above is better suited as a CT and one is better suited as a VT.